# API for creating new Powerpoint AutoShapes

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, shapes

I want to know if there is an API for creating powerpoint autoshapes and optionally adding them to the Powerpoint gallery. What I want is to create new autoshapes with connection points (green circles) and stretch/resizing nodes (yellow squares).

Please don't suggest me to combine existing shapes, that's not what I am looking for. This is a programming question.

**EDIT**: For more clarification: Let's say I want to have a gallery for drawing a network. So I want autoshapes for laptops and server, and the network pipe. Those shapes shall have connection points, and the pipe shape shall be scaled correctly, leaving always a perfect circle at the end. Those are "smart" shapes, not only dumb combinations of other shapes.

Comment: Have you seen something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959849/powerpoint-c-sharp-add-in-shape-grouping-issue

Comment: @cFrozenDeath: that's not what I am looking for. As mentioned, I don't want to combine existing shapes. I want to create my own shape from the ground up, add connector and sizing grips, and expose in a gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Microsoft has not exposed any API for expanding the built-in set of AutoShapes. You can't create them using the same tools as Microsoft used, and you can't add anything to the built-in Gallery.

You can make a suggestion to Microsoft via UserVoice:
https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/