# c# Error with inserting more than one shape group on the slide

Tags: c#, powerpoint, add-in

UPD: Maybe it helps. This is details of my Error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException   HResult=0x80070005
>   Message=Grouping disabled for selected shapes (Для выделенных фигур
>   группирование отключено).   Source=FirstPPTAddIn   StackTrace:    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ShapeRange.Group()    at
>   FirstPPTAddIn.MyRibbon.OnShapeButton(IRibbonControl control) in
>   D:\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\FirstPPTAddIn\FirstPPTAddIn\MyRibbon.cs:line 84

I added my add-in to Exeption Settings and when I've run code for the second group set I got two additional shapes on the slide without grouping. I don't understand why the last line of code doesn't work. 
I can just "copy-past" the first group set many times and make changes with them, but I need add them by button.

---

I used [this code for grouping shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11960124/10451426). But it allows to put just one shape groups only. What I need to change in code for inserting unlimited shape groups on the one slide?

Part of code

```
    PowerPoint._Application myPPT = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    PowerPoint.Slide curSlide = myPPT.ActiveWindow.View.Slide;
    string[] myRangeArray = new string[2];
    myRangeArray[0] = "shape1";
    myRangeArray[1] = "shape2";
    curSlide.Shapes.Range(myRangeArray).Group();
```

When I try to insert second shape group I have an error in the last line says `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "grouping is disabled for selected shapes"`.

Thanks!

Comment: We don't put "solved" in the title. Accepting an answer is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine solved this problem today. He add counter for the shapes in Array. The part of code below

```
private int count = 0;
public void OnButton(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
     var shape1Name = "shape1" + count;
     var shape2Name = "shape2" + count;
...
     shape1.Name = shape1Name;
     shape2.Name = shape2Name;
...
     string[] myRangeArray = new string[2];
     myRangeArray[0] = (shape1Name);
     myRangeArray[1] = (shape1Name); 
     curSlide.Shapes.Range(myRangeArray).Group(); 
     count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That may be due to The file is already in use.Try to manually dump the powerpoint.exe after adding shape 1

An UnauthorizedAccessException can be one of the following reason:

- The caller does not have the required permission.
- The file is an executable file that is in use.
- Path is a directory.
- Path specified a read-only file.

Comment: I opened Powerpoint from the Windows Start button and run my Add-in, so the 1st group shape was inserted fine, but another one were inserted without grouping. Just 2 separate shapes in the same place. I don't understand why line `curSlide.Shapes.Range(myRangeArray).Group();` doesn't work?

Comment: A guess:  one or more of the shapes you're trying to group is a placeholder (a shape of .Type=14); PowerPoint does not allow these to be grouped.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg no, they are msoAutoShape , msoAutoShape. Checked by this code `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(shape1.Type + " , " + shape2.Type);` if I use right code for checking

Comment: @LenaKire OK, not a bad guess, but the wrong one in this case.